# Using JDBC template, How can I update a column in every customer in a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, jdbc, jdbctemplate

So, I am trying to create a function that when called updates the lastEmailed column for every customer in the database called customers, but I can't seem to find out an approach that seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Also, the input style is in the format 2014-12-09 14:20:47 (datetime). ** this is a NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.

```
public void updateTime(String timeSent){
//        String query = "UPDATE customers SET lastEmailed ='" + timeSent+"'";
//        String query = "UPDATE customers SET lastEmailed = ?";
//         String query = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS "
//        this.jdbcTemplate.
//        this.jdbcTemplate.execute(query);
//        this.jdbcTemplate.update


//        SqlParameterSource [] parameterSource =         SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(this.getCustomerList().toArray());
//        this.jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (id,lastEmailed) VALUES         (:customerNumber, " +timeSent + ")", parameterSource);
```

Comment: Any error messages? If so, please edit your question and add it. And as doubt, why are you trying to change all costumers to same value? It seems hush to me even though I don't know your requirements

Comment: The code was incomplete, as I couldn't figure out how to run it (i.e. which statement to use, and  how to use jdbctemplate to update it). And yes, I am trying to update every customers lastEmailed column only because that is the requirement. I couldn't use update statement because I need more inputs into the execute function, like a map.

Comment: How does jdbcTemplate is instantiated?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Sorry, should have mentioned that, it's a NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, thanks! Will edit the post as well.